# Are NTSC and PAL affecting display rate

Tags: analog, display

I understand that the NTSC TV signal is 30hz and PAL is 25hz, but if NTSC and PAL are TV signal standards how could they affect display rate(Hz) for input devices e.g. when you connected and old game console (signal goes from console to TV). If I am not wrong analog input was the same in USA and Europe. Sow how come that there were consoles(or games) for NTSC and PAL ?

I know it may not be entirely electrical question but since signal coding is closely related to electronics I decided to post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only do the two TV systems run at a different frequency, but the difference in frequency also dictates a difference in frame size.  PAL is 625 lines, whereas NTSC is 525 lines.  That means that games (and the consoles) have to account for that difference in size in their graphics and playfields.

And then, on top of that, the two systems both use a different colour coding scheme<sup>1</sup>.  The hardware in the console has to be able to do the right colour encoding to be able to display on the right kind of screen.  You can't just plug a PAL console into an NTSC screen and expect it to have a clue what is going on - the same the other way around.

Most games consoles tied the action to the video output frequency.  Frames were calculated and drawn at the same frequency as the screen, so the gameplay was often quicker on an NTCS console than on a PAL console.  The internals of the console had to account for that change in speed, and so they would usually have a different core clock (and different crystal value) for NTCS devices as compared to PAL devices.

So you see, the TV standard the console is designed to work with affects a lot more than just the frequency of the TV signal.

---

<sup>1</sup> NTSC used to be known as "Never The Same Colour" as the colour coding system used in it was quite poor by comparison to PAL.  You could never quite trust how the colours would be represented from one device or broadcast to the next.

Comment: Add to that that an old fashion NTSC TV, even if the coding and colour space were the same, would not even check in the input frequency and assume it to create its scan lines. Same for PAL, so even if all else was the same, it'd still create a mess on your screen. Before controllers were added to TVs.

Comment: @Majenko Does it matter anymore for digital TV I mean I ve heard that Europe digital television is 50hz and USA is 60hz and they originate from NTSC and PAL. But when we have inputs/outputs like hdmi does it affect current generation consoles ?

Comment: Digital TV uses completely different timing systems than old fashioned analog PAL and NTCS. Yes, at the low end there are NTSC-like and PAL-like frame rates and dimensions, like 576p/480p, but when you get to the higher resolutions, like 1080p, they are universal. They no longer have any tie to the line frequency. I am not aware of a digital TV that can't display both the PAL- and NTSC-like progressive scan frame sizes.

Comment: The NTSC- and PAL-like frame sizes are only really relevant when transferring old analog video into a digital format, and with upscaling and post processing etc it's not really an issue now anyway.  With HD TV there is certainly no tie between where you are and what resolution you can display.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for answers. It is just weird that modern consoles like ps4 which doesn't even support analog are still distingueshed into NTSC and PAL(the same for games)

Comment: That'll be to force you to buy a different version and not import cheap ones from overseas. Just like DVD region codes.